# CSS shorthand vs longhand?

Tags: css, performance

Which one better? Using shorthand like:

```
padding:5px 10px 15px 20px;
```

Or using longhand like:

```
padding-top:5px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-left:20px;
```

Related to:

- performance (browser performance, filesize)
- documentation (easy maintenance by developer)
- and others

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- You shouldn't worry about CSS performance unless you have profiled the page load and it has became the bottleneck (I doubt, it is almost always multiple HTTP requests and images).
- Any competent developer can remember clockwise from top for the order of values.
- Shorthand means less bytes to be sent, which a CSS minifier doesn't optimise itself (I don't think).
- I'd only use the long method if setting one value, e.g. `padding-left: 3px`.

Comment: Imagine doing all CSS in longhand... nightmare!

Comment: I am not seeing the specificity of shorthand vs. longhand in the jsFiddle. In fact, it looks like it makes no difference in specificity, [whichever one is lowest always wins](http://jsfiddle.net/kfxbm/1/).

Comment: The comment about specificity is incorrect. CSS is read top to bottom so any shorthand rule will override any previous longhand rule.

Comment: @Empereol so if a rule is either shorthandedd or longhanded, makes no difference. right?