# why is css longhand equivalent usefull

Tags: css, gruntjs, shorthand

I was looking for a grunt tool to parse my css and tell me when I can convert longhand css properties to shorthand. My way of thinking that this makes css smaller, easier to understand.

So basically if it will find

```
.mydiv{
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(images/bg.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

It would change it to:

```
.mydiv{
  background: #000 url(images/bg.gif) no-repeat top right;
  font: italic bold .8em/1.2 Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

To my surprise I was not able to find such plugin, but on the other side I found a lot of them which convert shorthand properties to longhand. This raised a question:

**why do people want to convert their nice and clean shorthand equivalents to longhand?** is there any valid reason except:

- I like it to be longer
- some really outdated browser like IE 7 screws up something. (by outdated I mean IE <=7, chrome, ff, safari 2 versions lower then current)

**P.S.** also I am not asking for a grunt plugin, if someone knows one, please let me know.

**P.P.S** I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959652/css-shorthand-vs-longhand) and the person is concerned with: performance and documentation. I do not care about these things because: people in my team can read and understand shorthand and prefer it, and I know that performancewise (for parsing rules) it makes really tiny difference (if any) and it is smaller in case of bandwidth.

What I am concerned is that may be I will get different representations in some browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css shorthand vs longhand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959652/css-shorthand-vs-longhand)

Comment: @joe I do not think that this is a duplicate. I added an explanation in question to back up my thoughts.

Comment: I think it's either a duplicate, or entirely off topic, as it's basically a discussion question.

Comment: @Joe can not understand how can it be offtopic. Basically what I am asking is this: what can I break with shorthand properties. It is not a discussion, open-end, preference question. I want to see that if I will use this short rule instead of this long rule, my front end would be screwed up.

Comment: If that's what you're concerned about then the duplicate is a duplicate.  Its answer is effectively saying 'do shorthand', with discussion about what could be different.

Comment: @SalvadorDali maybe you will be interested in [csso](https://github.com/css/csso).

Comment: @raidendev thank you, have you tried it, because there is absolutely no information in github

Comment: @SalvadorDali, yes I've used it, but it's slightly not what you question is about, just a great tool to do css structural optimizations like split blocks with same selectors or same rules into one, shorhanding paddings and margins, etc. Little bit more detailed description available [here](http://ru.bem.info/tools/optimizers/csso/) but it's in russian, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes is necessary, so you can exercise finer control over your styles so that you can create things outside the typical case.

Consider this example of long hand border syntax:

```
section{
  max-width: 60em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

This creates a very different border then usual. There is no way to accomplish is such a terse way with short hand alone.

Demo: http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/sixaL

Comment: also long hand is helpfull when you need to change a single piece when the objects css selector changes (:hover,:active,etc).