# Are there downsides to shorthand CSS?

Tags: css, shorthand

Let's say I'm defining the font-size of all the `p`-elements on a website. I'd do that as follows:

```
p {
    font: 14px/1.3 'Open sans', sans-serif;
}
```

This is so-called shorthand CSS, and stands roughly for the following:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

All omitted values will take their defaults. If you know what the defaults are, this is the easiest way to write CSS (in my opinion).

However, when you have a background, and just want to change the color, you'd write the following:

```
.container {
    background: red;
}
```

The thing I was wondering, is whether this has any downsides, compared to just changing the `background-color`, since that's the only thing you're changing. Would it be better to write is as follows?

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Does this for example have any influence on render speed, or is this only useful for overwriting just a single value of the background (in this example)?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have an SEO question this should be posted at [**ProWebmasters Exchange**](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) but check their guidelines first.

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate the speed or performance ?

Comment: This *might* help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959652/css-shorthand-vs-longhand

Comment: @DaniP: Good one, but doesn't exactly answer my question, as I'm more interested in the actual downsides of shorthand CSS. And though it does answer the performance question, I want to know if there are other downsides I'm missing. I do understand it being tagged as too broad or opinion based.

Comment: Another source of info http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-shorthand-longhand-notations/

Comment: If you really are expecting all other values to default to their initial values, [some shorthands can actually be up to *twice as fast* on certain browser engines](https://github.com/mdo/css-perf#background-vs-background-color). Of course, that test is not at all intended to be treated as canon and it doesn't test all engines anyway.